# Reading string arguments passed from batch file to python script

Tags: python, batch-file, parameter-passing

I have seen multiple posts on passing the string but not able to find good solution on reading the string passed to python script from batch file. Here is my problem.

I am calling python script from batch file and passing the argument.

```
string_var = "123_Asdf"

bat 'testscript.py  %string_var%'
```

I have following in my python code.

```
import sys

passed_var = sys.argv[1]
```

When I run the above code I always see below error.

```
passed_var = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Has anyone seen this issue before? I am only passing string and expect it to be read as part of the first argument I am passing to the script.

Comment: have you tried passing a string instead of a variable ? perhaps the variable is empty ?

Comment: also to run a python script you need to prepend the command with `python`, e.g. `python myscript.py your_argument`

Comment: This is how I am exactly calling the code. bat 
    'D:\\BuildTools\\tools\\python27\\python.exe testscript.py  %string_var%

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
for x,parameter in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print(x, parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have read your question and its formatting correctly, I think your `.bat` file should read:

```
Set string_var="123_Asdf"
"D:\BuildTools\tools\python27\python.exe" testscript.py %string_var%
```

Or better still:

```
Set "string_var=123_Asdf"
"D:\BuildTools\tools\python27\python.exe" testscript.py "%string_var%"
```

Where `%string_var%` can be passed with or without its enclosing doublequotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file should be a bit simpler, make sure you have your PATH set correctly or else this won't work.

```
python testscript.py [argument]
```